# Failed to detect DLL path in Win32::API

Tags: perl, winapi, dll, activeperl

I am trying to import a C++ DLL in Perl (Active Perl 5.12.2 Build 1202).
My Subroutine for this is:

```
sub _import
    {
        my ($func,$params)=@_;
        print "DLL Pass value: $func $params \n";
        my $retVal= new Win32::API($MY_DLL,$func,$params,'I');
        croak("Failed to import $func from $MY_DLL \n") if(!$retVal);
        return $retVal;
    }
```

I have added `use Win32::API;` and I have defined `use constant MY_DLL => 'D:\MyData\MYDLL_CON';  # name of the dll`

What I get when I call `_import("Init",'P');` ("Init" function which accepts a pointer), Command line prints:

`DLL Pass value: Init P
Failed to import Init from`

Note that there is a < Space > after "from". DLL exists on the path but still it WIN32:API function treats it as blank! Same perl script works on certain machine and doesn't work (gives above error) on certain machine. All machines have same configuration plus same version of Perl and everything. But It finds the DLL on few machines and doesn't on rest!

Dependency Walker doesn't show any dependency errors for the DLL.

I am clueless what's happening!

Comment: What is MY_DLL and how SOFTING_DLL is related to the code you posted? Why dll name doesn't contain extension?

Comment: @AlexFarber I forgot to update the variable name when posting the edited code..."MY_DLL" and "SOFTING_DLL" is corrected now... And adding extension didn't make any changes!

Comment: It might help if you checked what error you got...

Comment: @ikegami How to check that? I never coded in Perl... Is there anything simillar to `GetLastError()` in Perl?

Comment: Yes there is. [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) shows you how.

Comment: @ikegami Can you give me exact function name?

Comment: It's not a function. Read the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

`$MY_DLL` is not the same thing as `MY_DLL`. Get rid of the `$`.

Comment: No change with that! Just now it is printing "MY_DLL" just like a plain text!

Comment: Without `$` it's simple text/String... I meant that even without `$`, MY_DLL is not getting loaded!